# Simulate RabbitMQ cluster outage

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Actually I need to "turn off" my rabbit cluster (only 3 hosts in it). I couldn't find any commands to turn it off. Are there any commands to do this or I just have to turn off all 3 cluster nodes?

Any suggestion on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation presented [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) should provide you with what you're looking for.

But to summarize,

- there is no "one click" cluster shutdown
- when you shutdown each node, you'll need to note which one was the last up

> When the entire cluster is brought down, the last node to go down must be the first node to be brought online. If this doesn't happen, the nodes will wait 30 seconds for the last disc node to come back online, and fail afterwards. If the last node to go offline cannot be brought back up, it can be removed from the cluster using the forget_cluster_node command - consult the rabbitmqctl manpage for more information.

I'd definitely recommend reading the link provided as it gives additional information that would be very useful, better to read before starting than trying to digest on the fly if something goes off during your restart.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot!!